# Google Analytics return row names instead of numeric index

Tags: arrays, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using Google Analytics API to populate a dashboard. I'm curious if there is a setting I am unaware of that can return the rows as follows:

```
[0] => Array
                    (
                        [ga:pagePath] => /
                        [ga:pageViews] => 856
                    )
```

Instead of just 0, 1, .etc. numerical arrays:

```
[columnHeaders] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => ga:pagePath
                    [columnType] => DIMENSION
                    [dataType] => STRING
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => ga:pageViews
                    [columnType] => METRIC
                    [dataType] => INTEGER
                )

        )

    [totalsForAllResults] => Array
        (
            [ga:pageViews] => 2099
        )

    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /
                    [1] => 856
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /portfolio
                    [1] => 268
                )
```

I know how to do this with array logic but was just curious if there was a setting or something I could query GA with to get the first format. Couldn't find any info elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No there isn't**, neither in [`v3`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#q_summary) nor in [`v4`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest) (it would be terribly inefficient to repeat the dimension names for each row).

What you can do is define the index of dimensions & metrics so you can refer to values by name instead of index (below example in JavScript):

```
var ga = {
  pagePath: 0,
  pageView: 1
}

rows[1][ga.pagePath]; // /portfolio
rows[2][ga.pageViews]; // 268
```